# Is it possible to set local reference variable for dynamically generated elements in angular4?

Tags: angular

I am working in angular4. i want to set the local reference variable to dynamically generated elements like "input","iframes". Is it possible to set local reference to dynamically generated element.

Comment: I dont think so you can, you might try to add it `after view init` but i am not sure

Comment: Incase if i wanna add src for the iframe means i ll add like iframe.src="http://...". How to add the local reference?

Comment: try and use renderer2 in afterviewInit

Comment: This feels like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Instead of asking about the problem you are trying to solve, you are asking about your idea for a solution.  However, this potential solution isn't really clear, especially within the context of how angular works.

Comment: @Claies i am not sure if this can be done just gave a random thought not sure at all as i dont think we can tinker with the dom afterwards

Comment: no, that's not possible. Local variables are processed during compilation. Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: maybe you can achieve your goal with `@ViewChild(ren)`? as in traversing through the elements in the controller. I don't know how you would want to reference a dynamic amount of elements in your template